# Redis restore from rdb: all keys are persistent

Tags: redis, persistence

I have a Redis instance with some persistent keys and a lot of keys that have expired. Then I execute the `bgsave` command to get an `rdb` file. As a result the file contains all keys - persistent and not persistent.

When I restart Redis all the non-persistent keys turned into persistent keys.

How can I avoid this?

I want all non-persistent keys stay non-persistent.

Comment: I really hope this is some weird bug and not by design! Completely unexpected.

Comment: This isn't the expected nor normal Redis behavior - couldn't reproduce: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/d2664c0ce3cad9860b9f